# Zone file: SSL on one sub-domain

Tags: ssl, dns

I bought an SSL certification for one of my sud-domains. It works perfectly, but when I changed the zone file to clean it up a little, I went into a problem that I still don't understand.

Here is the simplified version of my zone file:

```
                                              IN A      1.2.3.4
                                              IN AAAA   2001::1
*                                             IN A      1.2.3.4
*                                             IN AAAA   2001::1
xxxspecialkeyxxx.securesubdomain        10800 IN CNAME  yyyspecialkeyyyy.sslregistrar.com.
securesubdomain                               IN A      1.2.3.4
securesubdomain                               IN AAAA   2001::1
```

What I don't understand is why it doesn't work if I remove the last two lines, like this:

```
                                              IN A      1.2.3.4
                                              IN AAAA   2001::1
*                                             IN A      1.2.3.4
*                                             IN AAAA   2001::1
xxxspecialkeyxxx.securesubdomain        10800 IN CNAME  yyyspecialkeyyyy.sslregistrar.com.
```

Why the wildcards can handle all my subdomains, but not my secured one?

Comment: *gets redirected* DNS does not have redirects.

Comment: Unless you break your securesubdomain out into it's own ORIGIN, why would it not be doing exactly what you've told it to do?

Comment: @sebix: by _gets redirected_ you mean `CNAME` entry?

Comment: A CNAME is not a redirect. It is a possibility to resolve a name to an IP via an intermediate domain. Wildcards do only work on one level, so "*.example.com" won't catch "foo.bar.example.com". Also, I don't get your question. You practically say, that the lines 6 and 7 do work and wonder why this is the case. The DNS client wants to resolve `securesubdomain.example.com` and looks that up in the DNS, the result is `1.2.3.4` or `2001::1`. Which is the same as for all subdomains, so.... I don't understand your question.

Comment: My question is that this setup doesn't work if I remove the last two lines and I don't understand why. In other words, all my subdomains works perfectly with the wildcard except for `securesubdomain` which requires to be written explicitly. This setup simply don't work if I remove the last two lines.